# F#: a complex record type and a DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, f#, datagridview

I have a record type like this:

```
type Rule = {extension: string seq; subdir: string}
let rules : Rule list = // ...
```

And I want to bind it's instance to DataGridView. All my UI logic is implemented with C#. What is the best way to do this? Just make a reference to FSharp.Core in my C# project and bind? Or to make some simple record like this

```
type SimpleRule = {extension: string; subdir: string}
```

and a function that converts Rule list to a SimpleRule seq, which is represented as IEnumerable in C#.
The second way seems to be the best because I don't need to make a reference to FSharp.Core and I will work with IEnumerable, but there is too much conversion code and I am having problems with writing it. Maybe there is a better way to solve the problem?

Comment: Can you explain what the binding to the DataGridView needs to be - eg do you want two columns, one for extension and one for subdir?

Comment: You're going to have a hard time binding to a record type if you want the binding to be two-way. You'll need a mutable object for that.

Comment: You can find some generally useful tips on developing C#-friendly components in F# here: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/fsharp-component-design-guidelines.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using mutable record. Also I've created some wrapper-class for my library, which have several methods to add/delete rules and apply them, so I don't use any of F# classes such as FSharpList in C#.